# How to prove that HF=FK. H is the orthocenter of ABC. DK is the diameter of O.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle. Let $O$ be the circumcenter and $H$ be the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$. Let $D$ in the minor arc $BC$. and $K$ such that $DK$ is a diameter of the circumcircle. Let $I$ be the foot of the perpendicular dropped from $K$ to $AC$ ($I$ in $AC$), and $KP$ be the perpendicular of $BC$ ($P$ in $BC$). Let $F$ the intersection of $IP$ and $HK$. Prove that $HF$ = $FK$.

(If you love geometry, trying to solve this problem is the good choice, use all your knowledge about geometry such as Cyclic quadrilateral, Similar triangles, parallel, tangent of the circle, orthocenter,Parallelogram, Midline of the triangles, Ceva theorem or Menelaus theorem, Euler circle ... . it isn't the homework, it justs the quzzle for you who really good at Geometry :D)

[image]

Comment: Math.SE is for getting answers you don't already know, not for posting "quzzle"s. (See the [Art of Problem Solving](http://artofproblemsolving.com) forums for that.) The site's `puzzle` tag notes *"If the answer is known to you please do not use this tag to 'riddle' other users, but rather to ask about the correctness of a possible solution or ways to extend and improve an existing solution."* ... Also, you [posted this question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3318372/409). Re-posting is not the way to overcome being placed "on hold"; you should've edited that question to improve it.